# MSMQ private queue messages are lost

Tags: biztalk, msmq

I am working on a biztalk project where I am using  msmq. 
The problem here is the queue messages are getting lost before receiving by the biztalk.. 
I can't use transaction in biztalk as it will decrease the performance.
Can anyone suggest me why I am facing this issue and a solution for this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd start by using transactions.  Have you proven that the performance hit will be too big?

Comment: Yes!  As I receive millions of files from the queue daily.

Comment: Is there any other way to go around without using transaction?  And can you please  help me in understanding why these messages are getting lost?

Comment: HOLD ON, what do you mean by this: "I can't use transaction in biztalk as it will decrease the performance."  What evidence do you have that a transacted queue operation will decrease performance?  99%, you are making an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Hi John!  I never used the transaction property for msmq..  But when I read about the msmq properties I found the below which is mentioned by the Microsoft.   See the below comment..

Comment: Note: If the Transactional property for the receive location is set to True; each message batch is submitted to the MessageBox database under the context of (MSDTC) transaction. The MSDTC transaction that is created for a message batch remains open until every message in the batch has been persisted to the MessageBox and placed in the appropriate subscriber queue. Therefore the duration of this MSDTC transaction is increased as the Batch Size parameter is increased. Since having a large number of MSDTC transactions open simultaneously can negatively impact overall performance.

Comment: How many messages in a single batch? I'm guessing just 1.

Comment: Since we receive huge amount of files we have set it to default value (20).

Comment: If we set it to 1 then the messages get accumulated in the queue and then the receive location gets throttled!  Can you provide any suggestion to overcome on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "lost before receiving by BizTalk"?  If you enable transactions, are they still 'lost'?  *Never make assumptions about performance.*  If you need transactions, you need transactions and just have to pay the tax.

Comment: I tried enabling transactions but there is some firewall issue with it.. I am still working on it!  Thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 3):

When messages are sent to a non transaction queue, they will be lost if queuing service restart or some unexpected event happens. For this not to happen, you can use Recoverable property of message when sending message. This is also documented here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.recoverable(v=vs.110).aspx). This property is also supported by BizTalk MSMQ send port if you are sending messages from BizTalk to queue.

Comment: It is worth noting that recoverable messages do not guarantee ordering or exactly-once delivery. Only that messages will be written to disk so won't be lost from memory on failure. If the order of the messages is also important you should use transactional queues.